# setTimeout() and $(this) produce a strange bug

Tags: jquery

I'm just trying to simulate live typing with this function:

```
$('#expenseAccordion').on('keypress', '.netAmount input', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.amount input').val($(this).val());
    }, 0);
});
```

This doesn't work and produces this strange bug:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

The jQuery line where there is the problem (l 4245):

```
hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];
```

If I delete all $(this) from the function and try thing like that:

```
$('#expenseAccordion').on('keypress', '.netAmount input', function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.amount input').val(4);
}, 0);
```

});

It works, but I really need to get the current element where the event occurs because I have more than one input.

Comment: Learn how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: I think Markdown has problems parsing the links sometimes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . Or I'm just bad with copying links.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this` inside settimeout does not point to the `expenseAccordion` element, you can use `$.proxy()` to pass a custom execution context to the callback function

```
setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.amount input').val($(this).val());
}, this), 0);
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Why `$(this)` inside setTimeout does not point to the expenseAccordion?

Comment: @gaetanm: Because `setTimeout` calls the function like `callback()` in which case `this` refers to the global object. This is explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 3):

Another common way is just create a local variable to hold it.

```
$('#expenseAccordion').on('keypress', '.netAmount input', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
       $this.closest('.accordion-group').find('.amount input').val($this.val());
    }, 0);
 });
```

Comment: I tried a thing like this before posting and it didn't work because I forget to replace the `$(this)` near the `closest()` by the var created. I'm so dumb...

Comment: There is a problem with this method: when you are typing something, for example "44" you will only see "4", there is an offset. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I'm confused as to why this suggestion didn't work for you @gaetanm. This would be a much better blog entry. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first `this` points to your timeout, so any selection you are making it's going to be null.

Here is how I would do it:

```
$('#expenseAccordion').on('keypress', '.netAmount input', function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(self ).closest('.accordion-group').find('.amount input').val($(self).val());
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: *"The first this points to your timeout"*: That's incorrect, `this` points to `window` or is `null` (if in strict mode).